# web page google map overlay from memory image

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set the Google Map overlay from an image created at the browser instead of giving a URL.  Is it possible?

Below is the example giving on one of the google help documents.  As you can see they set the second parameter to the URL.  I would like to use an image from memory rather than the URL.  I have seen where when doing Android development that is possible with the GroundOverlayOption.image but I don't see that as an option using the JS V3 API.

Any suggestions?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(**'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg'**, imageBounds);
historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Investigate "data URIs"

Comment: create a image.. how? using a canvas? if so you can use the URL from 'canvas.toDataURL();'

Comment: Data URI -- Seems to apply to CSS, can it be used with maps?

Comment: I am not writing to the canvas so getting a URL from it won't help.  Is there something similar for a memory image?

Comment: A data URI allows you to create an image tag from base64 encoded data on your page [link](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/). They are uses for embedded icons in the kmz version of [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, think it would work but after reading up on it I think I will have too many browser compatibility problems :( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: I think data uris are pretty well supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri